# Activating the Apple Thunderbolt Display speakers when Macbook Pro is docked

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, display, dock, thunderbolt

Sometimes, I don't get access to the Display Audio that my Thunderbolt Apple Display provides when I dock to the machine with my MacBook Pro.  The clunky way to solve this, is a reboot.  I've tried using the Apple Preferences (Sound), but that fails to provide the option, unless I reboot.  Here is what my system_profiler shows as available Sound/Devices after the reboot (and when the Apple Preferences *does* give me the option to select the bigger Thunderbolt display):

```
Devices:

    Built-in Input:

      Input Channels: 2
      Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
      Current SampleRate: 44100
      Transport: Built-in

    Built-in Output:

      Default System Output Device: Yes
      Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
      Output Channels: 2
      Current SampleRate: 44100
      Transport: Built-in

    Display Audio:

      Default Input Device: Yes
      Default Output Device: Yes
      Input Channels: 1
      Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
      Output Channels: 2
      Current SampleRate: 44100
      Transport: USB
```

Any ideas how to 'wake-up' the Thunderbolt connection to recognize the third item (Display Audio) without resorting to a reboot? Ideally, that would at least activate it as an option in the Apple Preferences menu.

Here's a picture of the Preferences:
[image: Apple Preferences Dialog]

Comment: I have a similar issue on occasion when connecting a DisplayPort monitor. I just open the sound preference control panel and select the display out (or worst case, select an AirPlay output to cause it to refresh the list of devices). Are you not even seeing Display as an option when you connect it?

Comment: I just added the picture. When it is 'fully' connected, the MacBook Pro & Thunderbolt display give two options for the 'Output'.  As you can see -- when things are squirrelly, I only get the internal, tinny, MBP speakers.

Comment: Ouch. I'd [file a bug](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) and hope it's something that is fixable in software rather than a hardware problem with your Mac or your display.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this annoyance too. Rebooting can be very inconvenient when I have a lot of work open. Unplug/plugging the monitor doesn't seem to help. After reading the answer above, I started to log out, canceled it and for some reason the display audio option was restored. Woohoo! I'll repeat same procedure next time and see if this was just luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the USB connection to the speakers is tunneled over the Thunderbolt cable to the Mac, you might need to hot plug that (disconnect and reconnect).

I would be curious if logging out of your user and logging back in restores the sound destination. If so, it's likely a software issue on Apple's OS X side. If not, then it's likely a firmware issue or hardware issue on the display side.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but that's how I'd try and corner the actual root cause/culprit.

Comment: Every once in a while, I get the same issue as expressed in the OP and hot plugging the Thunderbolt cable of the Thunderbolt Display usually takes care of it. When it doesn't, I undock the MBP from the [BookArc](https://www.twelvesouth.com/product/bookarc-for-macbook) (open the lid so it's not in clamshell mode) wait of the OS to process the change and then hot plug the Thunderbolt cable, close the MBP and re-dock it. I have never had to logout/login to get it to work, nor would I want to either. :) It is a nuisance but thankfully it does't happen that often and hot plugging fixes it.